# JSON response missing }]

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax

While moving an .aspx site from Server A to Server B I discovered that an AJAX GET request on one of the pages wasn't working as intended on Server B. The page in question makes three AJAX GET requests and two out of the three work. The last request pulls in the largest amount of data but it fails. Inspecting the page in Google Chrome shows a status of 200, but looking at the response tab I can see that the closing bracket ']}' of the JSON data is missing. The same call though works perfectly on Server A. The page on Both servers is requesting the same information from the same place, Server A's response looks like this '[{Information in here}]' while Server B's response looks like this '[{Information in here'. There is a catch to this, though the response on Server B if the information is small enough it will work. This makes me think that it is a character/data limit, but in the web.config file there is this:

```
<webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
</webServices>
```

Below are the specs for the two servers and a picture of the response headers for the last AJAX GET request.

**Server A:**

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (Service Pack 1).

IIS 7.5.7600.16385

[image: Successful response from Server A]

**Server B:**

Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter.

IIS 8.5.9600.16384

[image: Failed response from Server B]

This is what the call looks like as well:

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url: "/page.aspx?Action=GetInformation",
    datatype: "json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        userID: userID
    }
})
```

**EDIT**

Here is some of the c# code that the site uses.

Inside the page getting the request.

```
if (Action == "GetMyProjects")
{
    String userID = Request.QueryString["userID"];
    List<Project> projectList = SQL.getMyProjects(userID);

    HTMLUtills.sendAsJSON(projectList, Context);
}
```

SQL.cs

```
public static List<Project> getMyProjects(String _userId)
{
    List<Project> myProjects = new List<Project>();

    int proNum = 0;
    String proDes = "";
    int busID = 0;
    String busName = "";
    int conID = 0;
    String conTitle = "";
    String confName = "";
    String conlName = "";
    String proStatus = "";

    ParameterCollection parameterCollection = parameterCollection = new ParameterCollection();
    parameterCollection.Add("@userID", Convert.ToString(_userId));
    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = (SqlDataReader)runStoredProcedure(SQL.runspType.Reader, "ALL_Projects_For_You", parameterCollection, "EACRMDBConnectionStringArmData02");

    if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
    {
        while (sqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            proNum = 0;
            proDes = "";
            busID = 0;
            busName = "";
            conID = 0;
            conTitle = "";
            confName = "";
            conlName = "";
            proStatus = "";

            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(4)) { proNum = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(4); } else { }
            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(5)) { proDes = sqlDataReader.GetString(5); } else { }
            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(6)) { busID = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(6); } else { }
            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(7)) { busName = sqlDataReader.GetString(7); } else { }
            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(8)) { conID = sqlDataReader.GetInt32(8); } else { }
            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(9)) { conTitle = sqlDataReader.GetString(9); } else { }
            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(10)) { confName = sqlDataReader.GetString(10); } else { }
            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(11)) { conlName = sqlDataReader.GetString(11); } else { }
            if (!sqlDataReader.IsDBNull(13)) { proStatus = sqlDataReader.GetString(13); } else { }

            Project tempProject = new Project(proNum, proDes, busID, busName, conID, conTitle, confName, conlName, proStatus);
            myProjects.Add(tempProject);
        }
    }

    sqlDataReader.Close();
    return myProjects;
}
```

HTMLUtills.cs

```
public static void sendAsJSON(Object _object, HttpContext _httpContext)
{
    string json = getAsJSON(_object);

    _httpContext.Response.Clear();
    _httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    _httpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=export.json");
    _httpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-length", json.Length.ToString());
    _httpContext.Response.Flush();
    _httpContext.Response.Write(json);

    _httpContext.Response.End();
    _httpContext.Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: AFAIK the maxJsonLength property can be set to a higher value, does changing it help in any way?

Comment: Does your response actually exceed that limit?

Comment: Share your c# code.

Comment: @Nisarg Shah. No, the response I am getting is only about 34 000 character, or 38.5KB as Google Chrome is showing.

Comment: That shouldn't hit the max json length config limit. Can you try posting the same request through a REST client such as postman? Also, when you say response from server B works when info is too small, how small is the response in that case?

Comment: When Server B works it is receiving information that is 1 092 characters long and 1.4KB. Running the request through Postman I get the error "Expected ',' instead of '' ". It is doing this on the last bit of information that the SQL query returns. JSON seems to think that there is more data coming.